# groovy programming and git commit

Tags: groovy

I am stuck with this problem.
I have a list of files inside a folder which is inside another folder in github. The goal is to open all the folder and read the files inside each of those folders with the latest git commit.
Please help.

```
FOLDER1
--- Folder a
------ file a1
------ file a2
--- Folder b
------- file b1
------- file b2
```

I want to iterate all folders inside Folder1 and read contents of file with the latest commit ID in each sub-folder.

Comment: What is not clear - what do you mean by `file with the latest commit ID` ?

Comment: Hi @daggett :   def list = []
                    def dir = new File("github.com/sfappsec/security-pipeline-builds/github.com/my-service")
                    dir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES) { file ->
                    list << file
I am using this to get all the files inside the parent directory , but it error path is not correct

Comment: @daggett I am initially trying to list all the file under FOLDER1.

Comment: `new File(...)` could work only with file system and `github.com/...` is http resource. you should call `git checkout github.com/...` then you will have a copy of repo on local file system

Comment: @SarthakGoyal Please don't add code to the comments. Edit the question and add it there for all to see properly.